# SSO with the SBTSDK

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

i try to get Single Sign On working on our system. Basic Authentification already works fine.
What do i need to modify when using SSO?
I changed the managed-beans.xml settings like here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Social+Business+Toolkit+SDK+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Endpoint_reference_SDK1.0&content=pdcontent

When executing an example i still get prompted to a login-form. 
Observing the Object with Firebug i can see correct baseURL but authType is still on "basic".
Do i only need to set the managed-bean-class to the ConnectionsSSOEndpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to change Managed Bean class to `com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.ConnectionsSSOEndpoint` as shown in the documentation.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>connectionsSSO</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.ConnectionsSSOEndpoint</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>url</property-name>
        <value>https://yourconnectionsserver</value>
    </managed-property>
    <!-- Trust the connection -->
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>forceTrustSSLCertificate</property-name>
        <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

First of all, check if SSO working properly. Because if it was basic authentication, it would ask the password through the browser prompt (not with a login form).

There is a tutorial for that here: [troubleshooting issues with sso](https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/wiki/Troubleshooting-Issues-with-the-SocialSDK#fixing-sso-auth)

To test it by yourself, login the server-1 and then in the same browser session (on a new tab or so), manually type in the following URL:

`http://yourconnectionsserver/communities/service/atom/communities/all`

Then you can see if the problem is related to the endpoint or not.

To set up the endpoint, make sure the services are initialized with the right endpoint name, matching the tag managed-bean-name.

in JavaScript:

```
var communityService = new CommunityService({endpoint:'connectionsSSO'});
```

in Java:

```
CommunityService svc = new CommunityService("connectionsSSO");
```

Comment: The log files from Tomcat where the sbt is deployed logs: INFO: Unable to find LTPA token for request. How do i get Tomcat to find the LTPA token?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment? Which platform is your application working? In a standard configuration, Tomcat cannot provide necessary token for you. e.g. SSO can be used when your application works on IBM Domino and you configured your environment so that they share the same secrets for LTPA Token. SBT will grab token from your cookies and will use it to authenticate into Websphere of Connections.